# How to avoid the type of coupling in the given code?

Tags: java, software-design, loose-coupling

I am stuck at some random problem based on [Coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)).

> A class Candidate with various methods for getting information about the candidate. One of such methods is `getScore()` score obtained by the candidate. Suppose we have another class CompScience that stores the details of candidates who are eligible to apply for the admission in Computer Science stream. Class CompScience has a method named `isEligibleToApply()` which returns true if a candidate has score more than 350. One of the structure for this method `isEligibleToApply(`) is given below:

```
boolean isEligibleToApply(Candidate  c) {
integer score = c.getScore();
Return true if Score is more than 350
}
```

In this case, if we change the `getScore()` method of Candidate class in some way (for example, by renaming it), we might also have to change the `isEligibleToApply()` method of CompScience class.

---

If I change the name of method getScore(), then it should also be changed in isEligibleToApply() method. This always happens as we change the names and wikipedia suggests this as content-coupling.

Is there any way that no changes are possible in isEligibleToApply() method and code is made loose coupled. I searched about loose coupling and got some suggestions to use interfaces to make the code loose coupled.

Any hints/suggestions ?

Comment: The only way to do it otherwise is to pass in just the int score as a parameter; but then you've got the problem that you can pass in *any* int, not just one which is semantically a `Candidate`'s score. That's a real problem; renaming the method is not, because tools exist to do it for you.

Comment: There's not really any difference. Using an interface doesn't mean you won't want to change the name at a later time and have the same problem. The key would be not to change the name but if you did take the above advice and use an IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to address this problem is to extract public interface from your `Candidate` class. This interface will declare the API contract that should never change in breaking manner. Even if you decide to rename or remove `getScore` method from the implementation, interface will force you to provide implementation of the old method for compatibility.

Needless to say, `CompScience` in this case will take interface as an argument for `isEligibleToApply`.

And one more note. This approach makes sense only when `Candidate` and `CompScience` are exposed as part of your public API. Or, at least, they are public within your project.

In some cases, such as inside a private module, it doesn't make sense to decouple things just for the sake of it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot escape the need to replace the locations where a method is used when you change the method. You can do stuff like writing a `CandidateScoreCalculator` class, which might have a method called `getScore(Candidate c);` which you can use inside the `isEligibleToApply()` method, but when **that** `getScore()` method get changed you have to change it as well at the locations where you use that method.